# Directory and Sub Directory listing

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to list the directory name (only name, not full path) and sub directories (only name, not full path) inside it. There is only one level of sub directories. I used below script to do this:

```
@echo off&setlocal enableextensions

for /r  "PATH" %%G in (.) do (
Pushd %%G
for %%* in (.) do set MyDir=%%~n*
echo %MyDir% 
popd
)
endlocal&goto :eof
```

The problem with the above script is that it is showing root directory with the full path. How can I just make it show the directories in relation to the one I am working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking you at your word that you only want one level of child folders:

```
@echo off
for %%A in ("yourRootPath\*") do for /d %%B in ("%%~A\*") do echo %%~nxA\%%~nxB
```

If your root path is passed in as a batch parameter then the solution is even easier

```
@echo off
for /d %%B in ("%~1\*") do echo %~nx1\%%~nxB
```

Comment: Now I am Trying to rename files inside subfolders using---for %%A in ("Mypath") do for /d %%B in ("%%~A\*")  do  (
cd %%~nxA\%%~nxB
FOR %%v IN (A20*.*) DO REN "%%v"  "%%~nxB_%%v"
)---.But renaming of files in only one sub folder is possible. How can I do it in each sub folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for %f in ("C:\Some\Path\Like\This") do echo "%~nf"
```

to display only:

```
"This"
```

If it is the root like this:

```
for %f in ("C:\") do echo "%~nf"
```

it will display ***nothing*** like:

```
""
```

But you said:

> problem with the above script is it showing root directory wit full path.

Do you mean, for example, when run at the root of the drive it will display:

```
C:\
  or
\
```

What is it actually displaying and what do you want to display in case of the root ? I guess it should be ***nothing*** (empty), but that may not be what you want.

Let me know what you want for this case and I will see if I can fix your batch file.

**Edit:**

I guess what you mean by "root" is whatever directory you are starting your search from. I thought you meant you were running the batch file in the drive-root like "C:\".

This batch file should do what you want...

If you save it to a file named:

```
getdirname.cmd
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
getdirname.cmd "C:\Some\PATH"
getdirname.cmd C:\Some\PATH
```

if you run it without any arguments like this:

```
getdirname.cmd
```

it will use the current directory as the starting point.

Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off


set "zstartpath=%~1"
if "%zstartpath%."=="." set "zstartpath=."


for %%f in ("%zstartpath%") do set "zfullpath=%%~dpnxf\"


for /r "%zfullpath%" %%f in (.) do call :work "%%~f"

set "zdfname="
set "zdp="
set "zdpath="
set "zfullpath="
set "zstartpath="
set "ztarget="

goto :EOF



:work

set "ztarget=%~1"

for %%g in ("%ztarget%") do set "zdpath=%%~dpnxg"

for %%g in ("%zdpath%") do set "zdfname=%%~nxg"

echo "%zdfname%"

goto :EOF
```

I have a directory structure like:

```
C:\Some\PATH
C:\Some\PATH\aaa
C:\Some\PATH\bbb
C:\Some\PATH\ccc
```

If I am logged into (CD) the path:

```
C:\Some
```

and I run getdirname like any of:

```
getdirname C:\Some\PATH
getdirname C:.\Path
getdirname C:Path
getdirname .\Path
getdirname Path
```

the output will look like:

```
"PATH"
"aaa"
"bbb"
"ccc"
```

If I run getdirname like:

```
getdirname C:
getdirname .
getdirname .\
```

the output will look like:

```
"Some"
"PATH"
"aaa"
"bbb"
"ccc"
```

If I run getdirname like:

```
getdirname \
getdirname C:\
```

and run the batch file, the output will look like:

```
""
"Some"
"PATH"
"aaa"
"bbb"
"ccc"
```

Let me know if this is doing what you need, or if it needs any "adjustments".

Comment: To display presently working directory we can use for  %%* in (.) do set MyDir=%%~n*  .But I want to list sub directories as well. That is why I am recursively accessing the sub dirs using for /r.